# How to integrate $\int 1/(x^7 -x) dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, rational-functions

How should I proceed about this integral? 
$$\int {1/(x^7 -x)} dx$$

I've tried integration by parts or substitution but I can't seem to solve it. Can I have some hints on how should I get started?

These are some of the things I've tried:

IBP: $u = \frac {1}{x^6-1}$, $du = \frac {-5x^6}{x^6-1}$, $dv = \frac 1x dx$, $v = \ln|x|$

Tried substitution method, but not successful.

Comment: If you can't think of anything else: $x^7-x=x(x^3+1)(x^3-1)=x(x+1)(x^2-x+1)(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ and use partial fractions.

Comment: For the lazy people who don't want to write out the partial fractions: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Apart%5B1%2F%28x%5E7-x%29%5D).

Comment: You made an error in your IBP.  If $u=\frac{1}{x^6-1}$, then $du=\frac{-6x^5}{\left(x^6-1\right)^2}dx$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The **cheater's method** is to "observe" that
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \ln\left(1-\frac{1}{x^6}\right) = \frac{6}{x^7-x}
$$

Comment: I wouldn't say it's cheater's method. Great intuition.

Comment: How to get to this? - Well looking at taking "partial" partial fractions with factors $x(x^6-1)$ - with the intuition that there might be something going on with the sixth roots of unity seems to get there - [$\ln(x^6-1)-6\ln x$]

Comment: Thank you @GEdgar for you explanation. Im kinda get what you trying to say. you provided me with the fastest way to solve this question :D

Answer (score 14):

One way to look at the problem is to say that it would be easy if the integrand were $$\frac{7x^6-1}{x^7-x},$$and also easy if it were $$\frac{x^6-1}{x^7-x}.$$Now take a linear combination of these to knock out the $x^6$ term in the numerator.

Answer (score 7):

Partial fractions: $x^7-x=x(x^6-1)=x(x^3-1)(x^3+1)$, and then use the standard factorizations of $a^3-b^3$ and $a^3+b^3$ to split each of the cubic factors into a linear factor and a quadratic factor.

Comment: Prof. Scott, can you help us with this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2788895/cos-n-is-dense-in-1-1

Comment: There is a bounty

Answer (score 4):

As in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226996/evaluate-int-fracx5-xx81-dx/227045#227045) example it is useful to extract something of the form
$$u=x^a\pm\frac{1}{x^a}$$
$$\int\frac{dx}{x^{7}-x}=\int\frac{1}{x^{4}}\frac{dx}{x^{3}-\frac{1}{x^{3}}}=\int\frac{\left(x^{2}+\frac{1}{x^{4}}\right)dx}{x^{3}-\frac{1}{x^{3}}}-\int\frac{x^{2}dx}{x^{3}-\frac{1}{x^{3}}}=I_1-I_2$$
Now in $I_1$ we may let
$$u=x^{3}-\frac{1}{x^{3}}$$
$$du=3\left(x^{2}+\frac{1}{x^{4}}\right)dx$$
So that

$$I_1=\frac{1}{3}\int\frac{du}{u}=\frac{1}{3}\ln|u|=\frac{1}{6}\ln u^2=\frac{1}{6}\ln\frac{(x^6-1)^2}{x^6}$$
In $I_2$ apparently $v=x^3$

$$I_2=\frac{1}{3}\int\frac{vdv}{v^{2}-1}=\frac{1}{6}\ln\left(v^{2}-1\right)=\frac{1}{6}\ln|x^6-1|$$

Finally,

$$I=I_1-I_2=\frac{1}{6}\ln\frac{x^6-1}{x^6}=\frac{1}{6}\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{x^6}\right)$$

Comment: thank you so much for explaining the approach in great details. May I know what is the name of this method as I did not learn this technique of integration in school.

Comment: I haven't seen a systematic discussion of this method and just inferred it from several examples. I am also not convinced whether it works fine unless for the carefully crafted textbook excercises

Comment: I see... I still have to thank for teaching me this new method to solve this particular question.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively the fastest method is to simply observe the following

$$\int \frac{1}{x^7-x}dx  = \int \frac{1}{x^7(1-x^{-6})}dx = \int \frac{x^{-7}}{1-x^{-6}}dx = \frac{1}{6}ln(1-x^{-6})$$

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{1}{x^7-x} d x & =\int \frac{1}{x\left(x^6-1\right)} d x \\
& =\int\left(\frac{x^5}{x^6-1}-\frac{1}{x}\right) d x \\
& =\frac{1}{6} \ln \left|x^6-1\right|-\ln |x|+C
\end{aligned}
$$
Replacing $7$ by $n$ yields the general case
$$\int \frac{1}{x^n- x} d x = \frac{1}{n-1} \ln \left|x^{n-1}-1\right|-\ln |x|+C $$